# How to group rows based on calculation?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having trouble trying to group consecutive rows (ordered by timestamp) where the difference between timestamps is less than 60 seconds.

Here's a sample table:

```
user    video       timestamp                  time_diff
----    --------    -----------------------    ---------
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:00 UTC       null
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:10 UTC       -10
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:30 UTC       -20
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:45 UTC       -15
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:04:00 UTC       -195
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:04:30 UTC       -30
Bob     bounce      2017-06-01 06:05:00 UTC       null
Bob     bounce      2017-06-01 06:05:20 UTC       -20
```

Desired results:

```
user    video       timestamp                    group
----    --------    -----------------------    ---------
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:00 UTC        1
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:10 UTC        1
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:30 UTC        1
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:00:45 UTC        1
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:04:00 UTC        2
Bob     balldrop    2017-06-01 06:04:30 UTC        2
Bob     bounce      2017-06-01 06:05:00 UTC        3
Bob     bounce      2017-06-01 06:05:20 UTC        3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for BigQuery Standard SQL - play with below:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'Bob' AS user, 'balldrop' AS video, TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:00:00 UTC' AS ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'balldrop', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:00:10 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'balldrop', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:00:30 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'balldrop', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:00:45 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'balldrop', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:04:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'balldrop', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:04:30 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'bounce', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:05:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'bounce', TIMESTAMP '2017-06-01 06:05:20 UTC' 
)
SELECT
  user, video, ts, 
  SUM(diff) OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY ts) AS group_number
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user, video, ts, 
    IF(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts, LAG(ts) OVER(PARTITION BY user, video ORDER BY ts), SECOND) < 60, 0, 1) AS diff
  FROM data
)
-- ORDER BY ts
```

it is not clear how you want to number groups for different users so PARTITION BY could be adjusted depends on it

Comment: I was hoping you'd answer! I can't believe it was this simple. I'm still trying to understand how rows that have a `diff` < 60 are getting the same `group_number` as the starting row in the partition. Seems like magic! Thanks as always! Learning so much from you.